# Is there any way to authenticate user from two columns which are in seperate table using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a flow in which I am authenticating user based on provided `email` and `provider_id` (for social sign-in). Right now I have column `provider_id` in the same table `users`. Following script is working fine to authenticate the user.

```
$loginAttempt = User::where([
    ['provider_id', '=', $request->provider_id],
    ['email', '=', $request->email]
])->first();
if($loginAttempt !== null){
    Auth::login($loginAttempt);
    if (!Auth::check()){
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
}
```

But in this way I am unable to store multiple social logins for an user. I am going to split into two tables. The second one is `social_login` in which I added two columns `user_id` and `provider_id`.

Now I want to authenticate user based on `email` and `provider_id` but now these are in two different tables. I tried same script with small changes but it does not working.

Can someone kindly guide me about it, how can I do it. I would really appreciate.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean that `provider_id` is now in your `social_login` table and  `user_id` in your `social_login` table has a `hasMany()` relationship with the user ID in your user table (meaning a user can have multiple provider_ids)? In that case, you could do something like this:

```
$user = User::where(['email', $request->email])->first();  //check if the email exists
if(!$user){  //return error if not
    return back()->withError('Email is invalid.');
}
//lookup the provider_id for the user
$loginAttempt = $user->provider_ids->where(['provider_id', $request->provider_id])->first();  
if($loginAttempt){
    Auth::login($loginAttempt);
    if (!Auth::check()){
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For clarity, your User model would have the following function:

```
public function provider_ids()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProviderID');
  }
```

And your social_login table might look something like this:

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('social_login', function(Blueprint $table)
  {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('provider_id');
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```